# Automating building footprint extraction in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, deep-learning

I am searching to automate the extraction of buildings from satellite images.

I found a solution but it was for ArcGIS Desktop
https://developers.arcgis.com/python/sample-notebooks/automate-building-footprint-extraction-using-instance-segmentation/

I am looking to implement the same approach but using QGIS.

I searched and I found out that we can use the plugin 'BREC4GEM'. However, it is not available for QGIS3 nor QGIS2.

I know that I can export the buildings from OpenMaps but the areas are not covered correctly by OpenMaps and only a handful of buildings are available (and there are thousands more like the image below).
[image]

Is there a similar approach or tool to extract the buildings from satellite images?

Currently, we are doing it manually.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the satellite image? Which bands do you have? Or is it just a RGB image?

Comment: OpenMaps? You mean, [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/)?

Comment: Segmentation can be done with Orfeo Toolbox (OTB) which is available in QGIS, see https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Applications/app_Segmentation.html and https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing/3rdParty.html#otb-applications

Answer (score 0):

You can try Mapflow plugin on QGIS. It has images from your desired area and extract some feature such as building, forest, roads, ...
You can install this plugin on QGIS and then for use this plugin you should create account in mapflow website (log in with Google) to get token. Refer to https://mapflow.ai/ for more information.

Comment: Mapflow allows a small area for automatic extraction for free. Need to pay for large area of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to approach this a solution that is simple and efficient could be the Magic Wand plugin.

Though it only analyses what is within the canvas extent when making polygon, so you may have to zoom over some areas, select a building and then pan and repeat and then merge the datasets.

If you do it at a larger scale the extent will be less precise, but it's still a simple an efficient way that doesn't require much, otherwise things like simple image classification should be enough, not sure why people think that deep-learning is better as there are sufficient and reliable simple solution to these problems.